# Resize huge images in Python (bigger than available RAM)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gdal

I would like to resize and split huge (1 TB) images to 256x256 pixel tiles (Zoomify / OSM / Google Maps / XYZ schema). Images would be in BigTIFF or PSB (Large Document Format or Photoshop Big) format.

What are the available libraries which can do this? I was having a look at GDAL but it was producing quite blurry output and I couldn't set it to interpolate better. Ideally I'd be looking at a Lanczos interpolator for such task.

Are there any native Python libraries, or wrappers for C based libraries which can do this? Can the Python wrapper for imagemagick do such thing?

If no Python library is available, I'm also open for command line based tools, which I can automate using Python.

Comment: You could go the spark-distributed computing route, if you find nothing better.

Comment: ImageMagick can do that with the -crop operator. See the tile cropping section at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop. There is Python   ImageMagick API and also Python Wand, I believe.

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at `vips` http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk and maybe its author, John (@user894763) will have some advice.

Comment: what format is the input image and output tiles....  In case of wavelet like MrSID limited memory during processing resolution can affect result quality. Also it could be lossy compression of output problem instead of wrong resize filter ... try to do tiles from smaller cropped image to see if it is better or not to check for this.

Comment: @Spektre I've added the file formats to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can process huge (larger than RAM) images efficiently. It's a streaming image processing library, so it can (in this case) decompress, resize, tile, and write all at the same time, and without having the whole image in memory or needing any temporary files.

The `dzsave` operator will write a DeepZoom / Zoomify / Google Maps pyramid. You can run it from the command-line like this:

```
$ vipsheader y.tif
y.tif: 104341x105144 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, tiffload
$ ls -l y.tif
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 32912503796 Jun 13 13:31 y.tif
$ time vips dzsave y.tif x
real    3m4.944s
user    9m21.372s
sys 7m20.232s
peak RES: 640mb
$ ls -R x_files/ | wc
 227190  227172 2784853
```

So on my desktop it converted a 32GB image to 230,000 tiles in about 3 minutes. That's with a mechanical HDD, it might be quicker with a SSD. There's a [chapter in the docs introducing dzsave](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html).

It has [a Python binding](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips), so you could also write:

```
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("y.tif", access="sequential")
image.dzsave("x")
```

The `access` option tells libvips that it should stream the image. It can read both BigTIFF and PSB. You'll find BigTIFF is a lot quicker and needs much less memory.

Comment: great answer! I had forgotten libvips and was already starting to think in some custom code.

Comment: How would you merge tiles back into the original image larger than the available RAM?

Comment: Could you explain more? Do you want to join a very large number of tiles together to make a huge image? I would ask a new question, but this might help: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1363#issuecomment-373331572

Comment: Hi @jcupitt, I know this an old thread but I was wondering if you have any resources on learning more about streaming and lazily evaluating larger than memory images? Even books or tutorials on walking through how to write a streaming image reader from scratch would be greater. I haven't found much except of course many terse codebases. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The libvips docs have a couple of introductory chapters. https://www.libvips.org/API/current/How-it-opens-files.html explains the general background. https://www.libvips.org/API/current/How-it-works.html is a more detailed run through the weeds of libvips pipeline evaluation. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/37531408_VIPS_An_imaging_processing_system_for_large_images is a paper from 1996 covering mostly the same ground. This style of evaluation is often called "chaining", which might help your googling.

Comment: @jcupitt Thank you sir! I will read through the related documentation and articles. I appreciate your fast response and the awesome work you are doing. Very much appreciated.